# Time complexity of algorithm to find all possible words of phone digits

Tags: java, string, time-complexity, space-complexity

I am studying this problem.

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-possible-words-phone-digits/

According to me the time complexity should be O(n^2) but it's mentioned there that time complexity for their algo is O(4^n) Why is it 4^n?

What would be the space complexity?

Comment: Where did you get O(n^2) from?

Comment: Because there are 4 possibilities for each digit, and there are `n` digits.

Comment: the user presses 1,2,3 so there are 3 digits & each digit has 3 chars associated with it. so i don;t see where does 4 come from?

Comment: Both digit `7` and `9` correspond to four characters